Trouble with counting misplaced pieces in Mastermind game implementation
I'm working on a C program to implement the Mastermind game, and I'm having trouble accurately counting the misplaced pieces when comparing the player's guess with the secret code. Here's the relevant part of my code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "secretcode.h"

#define MAX_INPUT_LENGTH 100

void random_code(char *code);

void checkCode(int *numbers, int *code){
int misplacedPieces = 0;
int correct = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    if (numbers[i] == code[i]) 
        correct++;
    else {
        int found = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == code[j] && i != j) {
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            misplacedPieces++;
        }
    }
} 
printf("Well placed pieces: %d\nMisplaced pieces: %d\n", correct, misplacedPieces); 





int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH]; 
char secret_code[5];
int max_attempts = 10;
int attempt_count = 0;

for (int index = 1; index < argc; index++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[index], "-t") == 0 && index + 1 < argc) {
        max_attempts = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        break;
    } else if (strcmp(argv[index], "-c") == 0 && index + 1 < argc) {
        char *secret = argv[index + 1];
        if (strlen(secret) == 4 && isdigit(secret[0]) && isdigit(secret[1])
            && isdigit(secret[2]) && isdigit(secret[3])) {
            strncpy(secret_code, secret, 4);
            secret_code[4] = '\0';
            break;
        } else {
            random_code(secret_code); 
        }
    }
}

printf("Will you find the secret code?\n");
printf("Please enter a valid guess\n");

while (attempt_count < max_attempts) {
       int i = 0;
       char c;
    while (i < 4) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
        if (bytes_read == 0 || c == '\n') {
            break;
        } else if (!isdigit(c)) { 
            printf("Wrong input!\n");
            break; 
        } else {
            input[i++] = c;
        } 
    }
    input[i] = '\0'; 

    if (strcmp(input, secret_code) == 0) {
        printf("Congratz! You did it!\n");
        return 0; 
    } else {
        int numbers[4];
        int code[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input[i] - '0';
            code[i] = secret_code[i] - '0';
        }
        
        checkCode(numbers, code);
    }
    attempt_count++;
}
return 0;
}

The issue I'm facing is that the checkCode function doesn't correctly count the misplaced pieces when comparing the player's guess (input) with the secret code (secret_code). The function seems to count correct pieces accurately but fails to count misplaced pieces as expected.
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to correct the checkCode function so that it accurately counts both well-placed and misplaced pieces according to the rules of the Mastermind game. Thank you!

We appreciate a [mre] i.e a program that demonstrate the issue.   In case you posted a snippet of checkCoce() and refer a missing header file.  Hard coding a failing non-interactive test case is a particular powerful way of communicating the issue.  Poorly formatted code is harder to read.

Don't forget that if the user guesses 9 in positions 1 and 2 but actually 9 appears only in position 3, only one piece is in the wrong place (the other is superfluous).  I don't see code to handle that case.

At the very least you need to tell for a given numbrers and code what the output is and what you expected (why is it wrong).

You need to keep track on which positions in the arrays that you have already checked/used. You can do this by marking the array elements with special (and otherwise illegal) values.
Further, check for correct value and location before checking for misplaced values as that has higher priority.
If you don't do that values like:
int numbers[4] = {4, 4, 4, 4};
int code[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

will count the first three 4 in numbers as misplaced and the last 4 as correct. That is obviously wrong.
With tracking the code could be something like:
void checkCode(int *numbers, int *code){
    int misplacedPieces = 0;
    int correct = 0;

    // Check for correct location
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        if (numbers[i] == code[i])
        {
            correct++;
            // Mark locations as used/checked 
            //    (note: using different illegal values for code/numbers)
            code[i] = -1;
            numbers[i] = -2;
        }
    }

    // Check for correct value but wrong location
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == code[j]) {
                misplacedPieces++;
                // Mark location as used 
                //   (note: sufficient to mark code)
                code[j] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    printf("Well placed pieces: %d\nMisplaced pieces: %d\n", correct, misplacedPieces); 
}

Notice:

This solution assumes that the input arrays are valid, i.e. only contains values in range [0..9].

This solution assumes that the function is allowed to change the input arrays.


Unrelated to the question:
You need to rewrite your main function to be much more strict when parsing user input. As it is now it only works when the user "behaves nice" and give correctly formatted input. But there are several ways a user can "behave bad" and break the reading of input so that the rest of the code will run using uninitialized values.

My issue right now is that it double prints the well-placed and misplaced like this:
XXXX
Well placed pieces: X
Misplaced pieces: Y
Well placed pieces: X
Misplaced pieces: Y
I cant understand whats causing that, but because of this I cant get the other functions to perform well, I try using malloc and memcpy to clear the input after each, but still get double input, Do you have any idea why it is happening?

https://github.com/yelyzaveta-samodid/my_mastermind/tree/main
this is my current code

@YelyzavetaSamodid Please ask another question for problems with other parts of your code. When you have asked another question you can ping me and I'll look at it.
